# Nested structures in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How can I create a nested structure in VBA? When I try the following code in VB Editor it is saying  "Statement invalid inside type block".

```
Type Functiondetails

    Function As String
    Sites(7) As String
    Values(7) As Integer

End Type

Type Financialdetails

    Metrics As String

    Dim f(10) As Functiondetials    

End Type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `Dim` from the 2nd Type (and spell `Functiondetails` correctly!);

```
Type Financialdetails
    Metrics As String
    f(10) As Functiondetails
End Type
```

You should be ok but it also may not like `Function` as an identifier.